# Centering a <div> in <body> fluidly

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to have a `<div>` in my `<body>` that is 95% of the page's width and height. I want this `<div>` to be centered on all sides, such that a 2.5% margin exists on all sides of the `<div>`. The attached code almost works, but the top has no margin, such that the `<div>` extends all the way to the top of the page. I am using a reset. Can anyone offer some insight as to why this isn't working as intended?

The most important thing for me here is that I have no interest in working with non-relative measurements. I am coming from a background in Android development and believe that anything I make should scale to (almost) any screen size.

I would also like to say that I am just starting with HTML/CSS/JS and at this moment have no intention of supporting browsers that do not comply with the W3C standard (IE). Furthermore i would like to avoid anything that seems like a hack or a workaround.

The CSS Reset in case your interested: http://79.170.44.85/rasmussenprojects.com/reset.css

A hard copy since I can only post 1 link and it seems best to link to the reset:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <style>
            html, body{
                background-color:rgb(25,25,25);
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                }
            .content-panel{
                background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
                width:95%;
                height:95%;
                margin:auto;
                }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="content-panel">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div{
  background: lightgray;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 95%;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My take would be that you just give the body a `padding: 2.5%` (and don't forget `position:relative`).
The div then should just fill up all available space with `position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;`

In general I also would work with `box-sizing:border-box`